# Removing string using "preg_replace"

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove some html/js tag using "preg_replace". Here's my html tag:

```
<style type=text/css>' );document.write( '@media Print' );document.write( '{' );document.write( 'BODY {' );document.write( 'DISPLAY: none; print: none' );document.write( '}' );document.write( 'TABLE {' );document.write( 'DISPLAY: none; print: none' );document.write( '}' );document.write( 'TR {' );document.write( 'DISPLAY: none; print: none' );document.write( '}' );document.write( 'TD {' );document.write( 'DISPLAY: none; print: none' );document.write( '}' );document.write( '}' );document.write( '</style>' );
```

I want to remove tags from `<style type=text/css>' )` up to `( '</style>' );`.

My code is like this:

`$result3 = preg_replace("(\<style(.+?)<\/style>/", '', $result2);`

But nothing gets removed when I run it.

I would appreciate your help. Also if you could explain the answer to me I would be grateful.

Comment: `$result3 = preg_replace("/<style type=text/css>/", "'</style>'", $result2);`

Comment: You can do that with substr and strpos too.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be $result3 = preg_replace("(<style(.+?)</style>)", '', $result2);

Comment: no one working.

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh i want to remove all of these html tag, not replace it to `</style>`. `</style>` i want to remove it too.

Comment: @Andreas that was a back door

Comment: @ainodoramaaa2 Check my answer. You need to use preg_replace twice to remove all style etc. from your string. Hope it works for you!

Comment: @ainodoramaaa2 What do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `preg_replace` like below (Tested Offline):

```
<?php
$string = "another text above here";
$string .= "<style type=text/css>' );document.write( '@media Print' );document.write( '{' );document.write( 'BODY {' );document.write( 'DISPLAY: none; print: none' );document.write( '}' );document.write( 'TABLE {' );document.write( 'DISPLAY: none; print: none' );document.write( '}' );document.write( 'TR {' );document.write( 'DISPLAY: none; print: none' );document.write( '}' );document.write( 'TD {' );document.write( 'DISPLAY: none; print: none' );document.write( '}' );document.write( '}' );document.write( '</style>' );";

$string = preg_replace("/<!--.*?-->/", "", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string);

echo $string;
?>

// Below Output will come
another text above here
```

Comment: Downvoter please explain in comment.

Comment: @ainodoramaaa2 Have you tried my solution?